# Write to a website using java

Tags: java, string, url, submit, urlconnection

I am currently working on reading and writing to a website, only using Java. I have figured out how to read from the website, to get all the content on the actual website. But I am not completely sure where to begin with the writing, although it seems as if it is a simple action I want to do. I just want to write a specific string to a text area on a website.

To show the code I have for reading the site, I have attached it below.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class Read {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("http://website.com/");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
        encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
        String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
        System.out.println(body);

        PrintWriter pToDocu = new PrintWriter("readText.txt");
        pToDocu.println(body);
        pToDocu.close();

    }

}
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is how to write the content of a string variable to a text area of which is on a website I have created. It is probably also pretty important to note that, for the info in the text area to be submitted a button called *submit* on the site has to be clicked.

Comment: What do you mean "write to a website"? You want to send Requests to that website (Get, Post, Put etc.)? Not trying to be discouraging, but your questions implies that you have a wrong idea how communication with websites/webservers actually works.

Comment: "clicking button", "typing into textfields".  These are things that browsers do.  What you've got in your code is raw HTML content back from the website.  So either take control of a browser using something like Selenium as @Abhishek says, or read up about HTTP and what browsers actually do behind the scenes.  Then you can POST HTTP messages (containing name/value pairs for your fields) back to the website - just like a browser does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Selenium tool to write data to websites. For example this [link](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2016/08/selenium2-webdriver-sendkeys-write-text.html) explains, how to populate username and password fields of login form.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think Selenium suits best for your requirement.
You can refer [this](http://dev.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_webdriver.htm) tutorial.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.